# Ajax doesn't send variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, send

I have trouble with Ajax. It doesn't send variable "xxx" to file id.php. Code:

```
var xxx;
$.ajax({
    url: "id.php",
    success: function(result1) {
        xxx = result1;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: "check.php", 
    data: "ids="+xxx,
    type: "post",
    success: function (result) {
        .........
        .........
    }
});
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: What does you PHP look like?

Comment: It returns text from mysql where id is xxx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because your second request is getting called before the first request completes.

you should have your second ajax request be wrapped in the success property of the first call.

```
success: function(result1){

    $.ajax({
        url: "check.php", 
        data: "ids="+result1,
        type: "post",
        success: function (result) {
            .........
            .........
        }    
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect format of data. Use JSON format:

```
data: {"ids" : xxx},
```

Comment: It is a race condition - `xxx` has not yet been set.

Comment: The format works just fine. It is the same format as jQuery's `serialize()` method would return.